# How to keep the content in a flex item within it's border on re-sizing the page with the cursor?

Tags: css

So, I have centred the content within the flex item like so. (the flex items just have a h3 and a paragraph within, in the mark-up.)

```
.flex-container {
  margin-top: 80px;
  display: flex;
  height: 90vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 2px black solid;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 200px;
}
```

So, rather than when I re-size the page and the h3 and the paragraph flowing out of the border, how do I contain it within the border no matter what when I resize the page? The reason I've made the flex items display: flex too is so i could centre the content inside both vertically and horizontally. But, obviously when I resize to a smaller screen, the h3 and paragraph go outside the border :S

Comment: you could try `word-wrap: break-word` to break the H3 text, so that it tries better to stay within the DIV. Or else make the `font-size` smaller, on smaller screens with a `@media` query.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot, or a working snippet?

Comment: @NicolasGoosen https://prnt.sc/26vv6wb